# Mixing XRef Tables and XRef Streams

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdf-parsing

It is true you can not have common XRef tables and XRef streams in a PDF file?
I thought this is what to be called a "hybrid PDF document"!

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Hybrid reference files are explained in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) in section 7.5.8.4 *Compatibility with Applications That Do Not Support Compressed Reference Streams.*

> it is possible to construct a file called a hybrid-reference file that is readable by readers designed only to support versions of PDF before PDF 1.5. Such a file contains objects referenced by standard crossreference tables in addition to objects in object streams that are referenced by cross-reference streams.

**PS:** It is not allowed, though, to freely mix both styles. As Leonard Rosenthol (Adobe *PDF Architect & Principal Scientist* and member of relevant standardisation committees) puts it,

> you can  NOT "cross the streams" (to quote the classic movie phase).
>
> If the original PDF uses classic xrefs, you need to use the same at append time.  If it uses streams, you need to use streams.

*([Adding XRef table to PDF w/ XRef streams?](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1034273?tstart=30) on the Adobe [PDF Language and Specifications](http://forums.adobe.com/community/design_development/pdf_language_and_specifications) forum)*

Comment: I knew this. I am afraid this only means that you can duplicate XREF tables in the "classic" and "stream" form for old and new readers. I am still interested in wether it is possible to mix both types more freely.

Comment: They are not to be mixed freely. But why didn't you properly ask in the first place?

Comment: I really do wonder who is so desperate about not being able to mix the two cross reference types to downvote the answer... <sigh>