# PDF incremental update for digital signatures: works with regular xref table, breaks with xref streams

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have been writing some code in Typescript to compute incremental update of two PDFs, because the library we use doesn't support this (pdf-lib)

The process is as follow:

1. Load PDF to pdf-lib
2. Make modifications (in my case: write a
   digital signature)
3. Write the new file
4. Compare the two files
   object-by-object and put the difference at the end of the original
   file as an incremental update, then write the xref/trailer.

My code works great, until I tested a PDF with an XREF table in an object stream. In this case, Adobe Reader complains with:

[image: adobe error]

From that I see, the format of XREF as streams is different, however my code always writes a regular XREF table at the end.

I have uploaded the original and modified PDF here:
http://www.wikiupload.com/JPM2J1I9H3HD4JP

The important bits are:

- The original file ends with an XREF stream:

> ```
> 8 0 obj
> ...
> endobj
> startxref
> 116
> ```

- The incremental update I got ends with:

> ```
> xref
> 0 1
> 0000000000 65535 f 
> ...
> trailer
> <<
> /Size 79
> /Root 21 0 R
> /Info 19 0 R
> /Prev 116
> >>
> startxref
> 152863
> %%EOF
> ```

My question is: if the original PDF contains XREF streams, should the incremental update also write the XREF in the same object as replacement? Or is there a way to make the two methods work together? Or is the problem unrelated?

Comment: Your link leads to a page requiring some login.

Comment: Other than that, your question seems to duplicate [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14964889/1729265); essentially no. *If the original PDF uses classic xrefs, you need to use the same at append time. If it uses streams, you need to use streams.* as Leonhard Rosenthol expressed it.

Comment: @mkl thanks, that's what I thought but couldn't find anything when I was searching. I'll write a streamed version, then

Comment: Ok, so I've closed your question as duplicate thereof.

Comment: As an aside, I hope your original file additionally has a %%EOF at its end. Without it it would have been invalid to start with...

Comment: Without xref in streams, all files are perfectly valid. So I expect the problem to only be about streams.

Comment: I just read the spec about cross-reference, streams, and they say `However, it is possible to construct a file called a hybrid-reference  file  that  is  readable  by  a  PDF  1.4  consumer.  Such  a  file  contains  objects  referenced  by  standard  cross-reference  tables  in  addition  to  objects  in  object  streams  that  are  referenced by cross-reference streams.` Couldn't we modify the original xref table with a XRefStm field, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: A hybrid is a very special beast. First of all it does not match your issue as there you start from a file with a cross reference _stream_ while hybrid files in all revisions have cross reference table sections, merely with an extra link to a plug-in cross reference stream.